# Store an array of objects in a another variable c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

I have a array of object which is generated dynamically. I want to store this object in a array collection.

```
object[] yValues = new object[] { 2000, 1000, 1000 };
object[] yValues1 = new object[] { 2000, 1000, 1000 };
object[] yValues2 = new object[] { 2000, 1000, 1000 };

objColl = {yValues, yValues1, yValues2};// I want to store something like this in a array collection.
```

How to store and push the array of object dynamically in to the new array variable.

Comment: Your solution is JaggedArray. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<object[]> list = new List<object[]>();

list.Add(yValues);
list.Add(yValues1);
list.Add(yValues2);
```

You have then one list containing objects for all arrays;

Answer (score 4):

> want to store this object in a array collection.

`objColl` musst be a jagged array `object[][]` to contain a array of arrays

```
object[] yValues = new object[] { 2000, 1000, 1000 };
object[] yValues1 = new object[] { 2000, 1000, 1000 };
object[] yValues2 = new object[] { 2000, 1000, 1000 };

object[][] objColl = { yValues, yValues1, yValues2 };
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for an arrayList?

```
object[] yValues = new object[] { 2000, 1000, 1000 };
object[] yValues1 = new object[] { 2000, 1000, 1000 };
object[] yValues2 = new object[] { 2000, 1000, 1000 };

ArrayList objColl = new ArrayList(){yValues, yValues1, yValues2};
```

You can access these items to the console by using the following loops:

```
foreach(var array in objColl)
        foreach(var item in (object[])array)
           Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
```

You can take a look at [this example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XBX6Do)

Comment: Stay type-safe. Why not use `List<T>`?

Comment: @HimBromBeere: yep that would be a better option if all are of same type.

Comment: Well, they *are* of the same type, namely `object[]`.